# Combine/ merge Dataframe based on multi values in column in R

Tags: r, join, merge

I have been able to merge dataframes like this:

```
df1 <- read.table(text="
   col1    col2    colx 
    A        5    hh
    B        3    jj
    C        6    kk
    E        7    mm", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2 <- read.table(text="
   col3    col4    coly
    A       5    be
    B       3    to
    C       6    go
    E       7   yo
    ", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

full_join(df1, df2, by = c('col1'='col3',"col2" = "col4"))
```

Which gives me this:

```
  col1 col2 colx coly
1    A    5   hh   be
2    B    3   jj   to
3    C    6   kk   go
4    E    7   mm   yo
```

But now I'm need to merge df1 with df3 something like 'A' %in% 'A | B'

```
df3 <- read.table(text="
   col3        col4    coly
   'A | B'       5      be
   'B | C'       3      to
    C            6      go
    E            7      yo
    ", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be we can use `regex_full_join` after removing the spaces before and after the `|`

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(stringr)
df3 %>%
     mutate(col3 = str_remove_all(col3, "\\s+")) %>%
     regex_full_join(df1, ., by = c('col1' = 'col3', 'col2' = 'col4'))
```

-output

```
#  col1 col2 colx col3 col4 coly
#1    A    5   hh  A|B    5   be
#2    B    3   jj  B|C    3   to
#3    C    6   kk    C    6   go
#4    E    7   mm    E    7   yo
```